# Is there a way to modify another object's member directly from within one object's function?

Tags: c++

all! This is my first post, so please be gentle.

My code is meant to simulate a rudimentary version of transferring money from one bank account to another. My code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Account
{
    virtual ~Account() {}
    virtual double get_balance() = 0;
    virtual double set_balance(double amount) = 0;
    virtual Account* transfer_balance(Account* to, double amount) = 0;

    long account_id;
    double balance;
    unsigned int privileges;
};

struct UserAccount : Account
{
    UserAccount(long account_id): account_id{account_id} {
        printf("Account %ld initialized at %p\n", account_id, this);
    };

    double get_balance() override
    {
        return balance;
    }
    double set_balance(double amount) override
    {
        this->balance = amount;
        return balance;
    }
    Account* transfer_balance(Account* to, double amount) override
    {
        to->set_balance(to->get_balance() + amount);
        this->set_balance(this->get_balance() - amount);
        return to;
    }

    long account_id;
    double balance
    { 0 };
    unsigned int privileges;
};

int main()
{
    UserAccount test_acct_one(23);
    UserAccount test_acct_two(98);
    
    test_acct_one.transfer_balance(&test_acct_two, 200);

    printf("Balance of Account %ld: %lG\n", test_acct_one.account_id, test_acct_one.get_balance());
    printf("Balance of Account %ld: %lG\n", test_acct_two.account_id, test_acct_two.get_balance());
}
```

Output:

```
Account 23 initialized at 0x7fff8e927a40
Account 98 initialized at 0x7fff8e927a00
Balance of Account 23: -200
Balance of Account 98: 200
```

While this code works, it feels a bit finicky to transfer the values like this:

```
to->set_balance(to->get_balance() + amount);
this->set_balance(this->get_balance() - amount);
```

However, when I try to do this:

```
to->balance += amount;
balance -= amount;
```

The output turns into:

```
Account 23 initialized at 0x7ffc37b91a40
Account 98 initialized at 0x7ffc37b91a00
Balance of Account 23: -200
Balance of Account 98: 0
```

As you can see, while Account 23's (the first one's) balance is properly set to -200, Account 98's (the second one's) balance neither increases nor decreases, and I can't understand why. Some explanation of this behavior would be much appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, transfering means withdrawl from one account and depositing the money into another:  `const double money = Rent_Account.withdraw(1000); Savings_Account.deposit(money);`  You code looks overly complicated.

Comment: please show the code that has the problem instead of the code that is fine and only explaining what needs to be modified

Comment: subjective: methods called `get_balance` and `set_balance` are not object orientation, rather the opposite. I see not benefit of the members not being public when anyhow you call `get`/`set_balance`. Not subjective: don't use floating point numbers for money, they aren't exact

Comment: I don't see the point of `set_balance`.  The methods that deposit and withdraw should modify the balance member appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've duplicated all your member variables in both types.  When you attempt to modify `balance` directly, it's trying to modify `Account::balance`, but `set_balance` and `get_balance` will use `UserAccount::balance` since that's available in the scope where the `virtual` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserAccount` class has a `balance` member and is derived from the `Account` class which also has a `balance` member. When you access the balance through the virtual functions in `Account`, it changes `UserAccount::balance`. But when you increment the member variable directly with `to->balance += amount`, it's `Account::balance` which is used because `to` is a pointer to `Account`.

Decide whether you really need to user virtual functions. (I don't see that you do.) If you keep them, remove the variables from `Account` and access the balance through virtual functions. If you decide to remove the virtual functions, you really only need one class so it's pretty obvious which number you're incrementing.

```cpp
struct UserAccount
{
    UserAccount(long account_id): account_id{account_id} {
        printf("Account %ld initialized at %p\n", account_id, this);
    };

    double get_balance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    double set_balance(double amount)
    {
        this->balance = amount;
        return balance;
    }
    UserAccount* transfer_balance(UserAccount* to, double amount)
    {
        to->balance += amount;
        balance -= amount;
        return to;
    }

    long account_id;
    double balance
    { 0 };
    unsigned int privileges;
};
```